# Identify if child div reached top and bottom of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a div inside another. The inner div (`#items`) scrolls within the parent div (`#itemWrapper`). I've got 2 arrows at the top an bottom.

I'm looking to hide the bottom arrow when the inner div reaches the bottom of the parent div and to hide the top arrow when the inner div reaches the top of its parent div.

My question is how do I get the distance / offset of the child div relative to its parent element to identify if it has reached the top or bottom?

Here is a [FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b899145q/14/)

I tried this to find the position of the child div to its parent. But did not work.

EDIT:

html:

```
    <div class="id="Wrapper">
      <div class="row">
          <img src="http://img42.com/p2OH4+" class="arrows" id="upArrow" height="128" width="128" />
        <div id="itemWrapper">
          <div id="items">
              <div class="content">
                  <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" class = "thumb" />
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                  <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" class = "thumb" />
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                  <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" class = "thumb" />
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <img src="http://img42.com/h1DoP+" class="arrows" id="downArrow" height="128" width="128" />
      </div>            
    </div>
```

jQ:

```
('#subGrHolder').offset().top - $('#subGrHolder').parent().offset().top - $('#subGrHolder').parent().scrollTop();
```

Comment: Your linked demo doesn't (appear to) have any scrolling functionality. The question would make more sense if the code was included *and* reproduced your problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks. It does have a scrolling functionality. Scroll over the blue bordered div. I've includes the html structure in my post.

Comment: Calculating top most position should be as easy as `$('#items').scrollTop() === 0` but for bottom, have you looked into `scrollHeight` of `items`? It can be used to calculate how much it has scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put here what I said in comments in detail. Hope this is what you were looking for.

**JavaScript:**

```
var items = $('#items');
var upArrow = $('#upArrow');
var downArrow = $('#downArrow');
var scrollFactor = 100;
var scrollLeeway = 2;

items.on('scroll', onScroll);
upArrow.on('click', onUp);
downArrow.on('click', onDown);

function onScroll() {
    if (items.scrollTop() === 0) {
        upArrow.css('opacity', 0.1);
    } else if (items[0].scrollHeight - items.scrollTop() <= items.height() + scrollLeeway) {
        downArrow.css('opacity', 0.1);
    } else {
        upArrow.removeAttr('style');
        downArrow.removeAttr('style');
    }
}

function onUp(){ items.scrollTop(items.scrollTop() - scrollFactor); }
function onDown(){ items.scrollTop(items.scrollTop() + scrollFactor); }
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/vdnnLy5f/).

Apologies if I have misunderstood your question entirely.